# Suppress Content Approval information messages

Tags: content-approval

I have a document library that has content approval turned on for students to upload information.

I'd like to remove the 2 content approval information messages that appear on uploading the file as in the attachment.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the developer tools in your browser to get the reference for those messages and then hide them with jQuery (or plain JavaScript).

This is what I use in a list but it should be the same or similar for a document library :

```
$('a[href*="WSSEndUser_ContentApproval"]').closest('table').hide();
```